# How to simulate soap response with JAX-WS 2.0?

Tags: java, soap

I am using JAX-WS comes with standard jdk (i am using 1.6). And I want to know how to simulate soap response for testing? For example, I can set the soap response xml as a string (which is read from file) every time I call a soap service.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

While several years ago it was perfectly fine to create you own simulators of SOAP APIs (for example with JAX-WS), in 2017 there are many open source and commercial tools available so that you do not have to do it yourself. You can use an [API simulation tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_API_simulation_tools) which will simulate the API you are using.

Here is a list of a few tools:

- [Hoverfly](https://docs.hoverfly.io/en/latest/pages/introduction/introduction.html)
- [Moutebank](http://www.mbtest.org/docs/gettingStarted)
- [SoapUI Mockserver](https://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/getting-started.html)
- [Traffic Parrot](http://trafficparrot.com/documentation/3.10.x/start.html)
- [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/docs/getting-started/)
- [Wiremock.NET](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a WSDL and a tester if your IDE allows.

So go to your WSDL url then replace WSDL with Tester.

That is how netbeans works and I configured eclipse to work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to work in raw xml using JAX WS and send the xml you need. You can work either at the application data level i.e. the message encapsulated in the `SOAP` envelope to be processed by the web service or at the `SOAP` envelope level.
You need to read about [Dispatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Dispatch.html).
There are examples if you google. E.g. [Creating a Dispatch client](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0707_thaker/0707_thaker.html)